# Getting a specific service recovery option for a list of servers

Tags: powershell

Apologies in advance for errors. I'm still learning Powershell.

I'm trying to check a specific service recovery options for a list of servers in AD

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -properties * | ?{$_.OperatingSystem -match "server"} | ft name -hidetableheaders | out-string
$Results = @()
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
      Invoke-command -cn $server -credential $credential -ScriptBlock {Get-WMIObject win32_service | 
    Where-Object {$_.description -imatch "nscli" -and $_.startmode -eq "Auto"}; foreach ($service in $services){sc.exe qfailure $service.name}}
    }
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Invoke-command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects
instead of strings.
At line:1 char:32
+ foreach ($Server in $Servers) {Invoke-command -cn $server -credential $credentia ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

If I run the command directly on each server, I don't have any issues.

```
Invoke-command -cn EXCHANGE -credential $credential -ScriptBlock {$services = Get-WMIObject win32_service | Where-Object {$_.description -imatch "nscli" -and $_.startmode -eq "Auto"}; foreach ($service in $services){sc.exe qfailure $service.name}}
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: NSClientpp
    RESET_PERIOD (in seconds)    : 0
    REBOOT_MESSAGE               :
    COMMAND_LINE                 :
    FAILURE_ACTIONS              : RESTART -- Delay = 120000 milliseconds.
                                   RESTART -- Delay = 120000 milliseconds.
```

Because I'm using sc.exe, I'm unsure how to output the list into a csv format but at least, I can get some information of which servers the service failure restart aren't set accordingly

Thanks in advance

Cheers

G

Answer (score 0):

Since `Invoke-Command` doesn't support the `-WhatIf` switch, your best bet is to echo the server name on console to see the server name that causes failure. In the debugging statement, the server name is enclosed withing single quotes `'` for, say, extra whitespace is easier to see. Like so,

```
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
  Write-host $("Now processing server '{0}' " -f $Server)
  Invoke-command ...
}
```

You could also try to write the `Invoke-Command` statements to console and copy-paste those to another a Powershell session to see which, if any, is the failing one.

For what it is worth, you seem to use variables `$Server` and `$server` (note the upper/lowercase difference). Though variable names are not case sensitive in Powershell, you might have uninitialized variables caused by simple typos. To guard against such, use `Set-StrictMode`. It will cause Powershell to complain about uninitialized variables, which commonly are caused by mistyping variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Should have responded earlier. Thanks guys.

```
# Get the credential
$Credential=Get-Credential

# Collect the server list
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties operatingsystem | Where operatingsystem -match 'server'

$Results = @()    

## Check service status 
$Results = foreach ($Server in $Servers)
        {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name –Ea 0 -Credential $Credential {Get-Service |?{$_.DisplayName –match “nscli”} }}

## Create a csv report
$Results| Sort PSComputerName | select PSComputerName, DisplayName, Name, Status |Export-Csv nsclient_service.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

# Check the recovery options for NSclient service on each Server
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
        { write-host "Checking " $Server.Name;
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name –Ea 0 -Credential $Credential `
              {$services = Get-WMIObject win32_service | Where-Object {$_.name -imatch "nscli" -and $_.startmode -eq "Auto"}; `
                    foreach ($service in $services){sc.exe qfailure $service.name}}
        }
```